# Gridview edit, update, delete and select events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, templatefield

I have a dropdownlist that is populated by the names of the tables in the database. Then when the admin chooses or clicks a table name. The gridview below is populated by the data in the table. The admin should be able to edit, update, delete and select. However the commands supplied by the gridview are not working. When you click edit it does not execute. Then when you click select it deletes. The commands have a mix up somewhere. So l changed the commands into templates so l can code them myself. However the solutions l found online do not work. Because one

1. The Gridview does not only show data from one table but multiple so l cannot be specific in my query that l want delete the row of a certain table but just say l want to delete the row of the table showing. This goes for all the other events
2. Code for like `editing GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex` does not work. It displays a

> System.EventArgs error. NewEditIndex has no extension method and is
>   not accepting a first argument of type System.EventArgs could be
>   found.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["tlcString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    con.Open ();
    //Populates the gridview with the selectedindex in the list. The selectedindex being the table
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format ("Select * From {0}", drpTable.SelectedValue), con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds. Tables [0];
    GridView1.DataBind ();
    con.Close ();
    }

    private void BindData ()
    {
    //Binds the data in the gridview with the database table and updating it if changes are ever made. The method is called.

    string strQuery = "Select * From {0}";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand  (strQuery);
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData (cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind ();
    }

    private object GetData (SqlCommand cmd)
    {
    throw new NotImplentedException ();
    }

    //this is the code for the commads after l turned them into templatefields. But l only wrote code for the edit button only. It would be appreaciated if code for the other commands is supplied

    protected void LinkButton1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Set edit index
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData ();
    }
//THATS all my code. The commands that were acting up were auto generated in the gridview properties window. 




<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
ForeColor="#333333" 
GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="False" 
CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
/>
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
/>
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" /></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: There are numerous things that could be causing this behavior mostly dealing with the data binding and postbacks. Please post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I am trying to post up the code but their app and mobile website cant seem to recognize my code. I will only be able to post it up in about 3 hours when l get to my computer. I also have a picture but it's not uploading on the mobile website and the app crashes everytime l upload it.

Comment: Please also post page code.
First problem that I see is that you are binding the gridview with 2 separate actions:
LinkButton1_Click and DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged  the second one looks fine but not the first.

Comment: I have edited the code and included the source page code

Comment: I looked at your code and there are simply too many things that need work. There are several approaches to performing CRUD operations on a gridview each with its own advantages and disadvantages. I recommend looking at a few examples online to determine which one is best suited for your needs. 
for example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/select-add-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/

Comment: I've viewed his code and l safely say that he was of no help. Because he still used the e.NewIndexItem which l said doesn't work on me. And his example was only based on one table. But my solution aims to find a method to perform CRUD events seeing that the Gridview is populated by different tables. Which have different names .With different table column and column names.